# Can I know if a file is a folder?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I have a String array with the list of files (files and folders) of a path:

```
File directory = new File(path);
String[] fileNames = directory.list();
```

When I try to read the file content:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
           new FileInputStream(path + "\\" + fileNames[i]), "UTF-8"));
```

If the file is a folder I get a FileNotFoundException.
How can I know before if a file name belongs to a folder. Perhaps by the size of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`File#isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) method to test whether a `file` is a `directory`.

```
File file = new File("test");
System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
```

Or, you can use [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method instead. It only returns the `files` inside the directory. That way, you won't have to check whether your `file` is a `directory` or not.

```
File directory = new File(path);
String[] fileNames = directory.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 3):

`file.isDirectory()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [isDirectory() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) of `File` class

Answer (score 2):

You can use your code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        if(fileNames[i].isFile()){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
           new FileInputStream(path + "\\" + fileNames[i]), "UTF-8"));
}
}
```